# How to set focus on a specific date in CalendarView knowing date is "dd/mm/yyyy"

Tags: java, android, calendarview

I'm trying to figure out how to set a focus on a specific date in CalendarView during activity creation, The date is known and stored in a separate string variable, lets say `theDate` and has format of `dd/mm/yyyy` Knowing this, can I make calendar focus on a specific date?

Assume calendar view is `mCalendarView` in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this method in CalendarView:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#setDate(long)

As for converting between the dd/mm/yyyy format to milliseconds format, I recommend that you store the date in millisecond format and only convert to the dd/mm/yyyy format when displaying the date. If you have to use the dd/mm/yyyy format, though, I would try the following:

```
    String date = "22/3/2014";
    String parts[] = date.split("/");

    int day = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

    long milliTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

And now set the selected date in the calendar view by doing

```
    mCalendarView.setDate (milliTime, true, true);
```

Answer (score 4):

this works on me :)

```
    String selectedDate = "30/09/2016";
    mCalendarView.setDate(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(selectedDate).getTime(), true, true);
```