# Fix CalendarView style

Tags: android, android-styles, calendarview

On Android 6 I get error in CalendarView. I tried find fix for me, but [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412402/change-calendarview-style) doesnt help me.

Now my dialog with CalendarView looks like:
[image]

And this code from style:

```
 <style name="Widget.CalendarView.Custom" parent="android:Widget.CalendarView">
        <item name="android:focusedMonthDateColor">@color/edittext_primary</item>
        <item name="android:weekNumberColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@color/edittext_primary</item>
        <item name="android:state_focused">@color/edittext_primary</item>
        <item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">@color/edittext_primary</item>       
    </style>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What is the issue? Sorry I did not get it.

Comment: @Saumik Bhattacharya - Black circle is my problem

Answer (score 1):

This line is causing the issue --

`<item name="android:focusedMonthDateColor">@color/edittext_primary</item>`

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583122/how-to-set-focus-on-a-specific-date-in-calendarview-knowing-date-is-dd-mm-yyyy) alternative approach, if it is required.

EDITED SECTION:

According to Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html), `android:focusedMonthDateColor`,`android:weekNumberColor`,`android:dayOfWeekBackground` are deprecated in API level 23.

Hence I tried the below approach and I could see the current date is being highlighted in a default way.

```
String date = "25/2/2016";
String parts[] = date.split("/");

int day = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, (month - 1));
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

long milliTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.cview);
calendarView.setDate(milliTime,true,true);
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: What's happening now? Is it the same issue again?

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko -- I tried something. Looked perfect for me. Please check the edited section of my answer and do let me know.

Comment: I use DatePickerDialog

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko -- Can you please try whatever I mentioned in the last?