# Update entered date in CalendarView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, calendarview

I have a Calendarview and an Edittext. I wish to take the date entered in the edittext in the format DD/MM/YYYY and set it on the Calendarview. The view should update the current date bubble to the set date.

I have already tried:
[How to set focus on a specific date in CalendarView knowing date is "dd/mm/yyyy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583122/how-to-set-focus-on-a-specific-date-in-calendarview-knowing-date-is-dd-mm-yyyy)

This is my current code:

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JUNE);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);

        long milliTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        CalendarView calendarView =  findViewById(R.id.calendar);
        calendarView.setFocusedMonthDateColor(Color.BLUE); //apparently this is deprecated so won't work. Not working without it either.
        calendarView.setDate (milliTime); //this is supposed to change the date but isn't
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, currently I am trying to set the date to 20th June, 2019. If this will work, I will be able to set date from edittext as well. The problem is it isn't reflecting on the calendar.

Comment: So basically you want entered text in editext to calendarview? You can simply done with using _SimpleDateFormat_

Comment: yea, just update the bubble to entered date

Comment: You can simply use _new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(edittext.getText().toString().trim()).getTime()_ . Also this is _DD/MM/YYYY_ wrong. This _dd/MM/yyyy_ will be right

Comment: It is currently in string format.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39787704/8762338 try this and check if it helps.

Comment: Hey @Astha, I have clearly mentioned in the ques that I have tried this method.

Answer (score 0):

I have read your question and i have try to solve this problem. pass date(time in milliseconds) in long type  value to set date in calendar view like this `calendar_view.setDate(milliTime);` try this code to achieve your goal .

**Code**

```
    calendar_view = findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);

  //replace date variable static value to your edit text 
    value    
  String date = "25/06/2019";
    String parts[] = date.split("/");

    int day = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

    long milliTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    calendar_view.setDate(milliTime);
```

Comment: Hey, I don't see any difference in your and my implementation. I am already passing the date in long type. Also, not working. :/